# Mask the First digit convert to in an account number

Tags: mysql

There are account numbers like that

12345664

123546

66662

1111

I want to convert in MySQL like that below

XXXX5664

XX3546

X6662

1111

I want to add the 'X' mark first all symbol more than 4 length characters

Comment: We know what you want. What have you tried so far?

Comment: `12345664 123546 66662 1111` are separate account numbers or Single Account Number? Also, You can't do this in MySQL as it is a DBMS storing the actual data. If you mask the values, then you will have duplicate values and lose control over data. The full account numbers will be stored in MySQL and the Script, whatever you are using, will mask the desired digits as required. Now what have tried till now? Share your code.

Comment: they are separate account numbers @Raky

Comment: @Raky Any possible to do from mysql

Comment: Then you should separate the values with a comma for people to understand. I hope you have read rest of my Comment too given above. Please vote for the solution that has worked for you.

Comment: @Hasintha Chamara, MySQL is a Database which hold actual data. You cant mask values in DB Tables. You should read the Data from DB table and then Mask the Values when displayed to webpage or an application. If you mask the values in the database table, how will you ensure Data Integrity. Ever heard something about Normalisation and ACID properties of DB?

Comment: @Raky Thank you I will try on webpage

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT CONCAT(REPEAT('X', LENGTH(account_no)-4), account_no MOD 10000) account_no
FROM sourcetable
```